# Review Board - rbt post - Error validating diff - fatal: Not a git repository: 'None'

Tags: git, repository, review-board, rbtools

I have installed Review Board on Ubuntu. Remote repositories are pushed/stored on the same server. I have added repository with remote path/full URL in the admin panel. When I try to make "rbt post" from Windows cmd or directly post diff file into Review board web form, I get:

```
ERROR: Error validating diff

fatal: Not a git repository: 'None'
(HTTP 400, API Error 224)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed repository path from remote URI https://example.com:8443/scm/git/my_repository.git to the local path /opt/scm_repos/git/my_repository.git.